# Can a google dataflow spanner to big query change stream be configured to only watch/post Inserts and ignore all updates/deletes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to set up a change stream from a spanner table to big query. The big query table should be a persistent record of all the inserts to the spanner table, but the spanner table will only hold the last 30 days of data before a clean up to delete older records.

Can a change stream be configured to ignore mod_types of UPDATE and DELETE and only pass along the INSERTS?

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do so.

All mod types are being passed when using the default templates

Answer (score 2):

Great question! You are right, change streams capture always all Insert, Updates and Deletes.
What you could do is to modify the existing Dataflow template code and drop events that are not relevant for you.

Here are a few pointers:

1. Our change streams templates uses the change stream implementation in SpannerIO, which is an Apache Beam connector. [1]
2. The Dataflow template code is published in the Google github repo [2].
3. You can apply a filter transform like in our example for ttl-transaction tag handling [3].
4. The build and staging process for customn Dataflow templates is described in [4]

A basic example to skip all `DELETE` events

```
pipeline
  .apply(SpannerIO
    .readChangeStream()
    .withSpannerConfig(SpannerConfig
      .create()
      .withProjectId("my-project-id")
      .withInstanceId("my-instance-id")
      .withDatabaseId("my-database-id"))
    .withChangeStreamName("my-change-stream")
    .withMetadataInstance("my-metadata-instance-id")
    .withMetadataDatabase("my-metadata-database-id")
    .withInclusiveStartAt(Timestamp.now()))
  .apply(Filter.by(record -> element.getModType() != ModType.DELETE))
  // Subsequent processing goes here
```

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner

[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/googlecloud-to-googlecloud/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams/use-dataflow#filter-by-tx-tag

[4] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/README.md#developingcontributing-templates